# <meter> With 3 Colors

Tags: css, html

I want to implement a meter that will be used as VU meter. At the momement I have this:

```html
<meter id="sr_volume_meter" value="0" min="0" optimum="30" max="65" low="15" high="45" style="width:100px; height:20px;"></meter>
```

But, in Chrome (at least), this show yellow below the `min` and yellow above the `max`. And I want to show red, if the value is above the `max`. How can I implement this?

Comment: FWIW: https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is replace the "sub-optimum" yellow with red, something like this would work for Mozilla and Chrome.

```css
meter {
    width:100px; height:20px;
}

:-moz-meter-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(230, 100, 100), rgb(230, 100, 100), rgb(238, 108, 108) 20%, rgb(204, 74, 74) 45%, rgb(204, 74, 74) 55%);
}
::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(230, 100, 100), rgb(230, 100, 100), rgb(238, 108, 108) 20%, rgb(204, 74, 74) 45%, rgb(204, 74, 74) 55%);
}
```

```html
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="0"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="10"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="20"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="30"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="40"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="50"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="60"></meter></p>
<p><meter min="0" low="15" optimum="30" high="45" max="65" value="70"></meter></p>
```

Or did you mean you want a two-colored bar, with the part below the "high" mark green, and red above it?